# Running two FTP sites both with SSL on the same server?

Tags: networking, ftp, ssl, ftps

I have built an internal ftp server on our network and am having it be accessed from the outside. The server is running 2012 R2 and has IIS 8.5. When I set up the sites I have the data channel open for a range and those ports bind to the sites. I can get one server to work with its set of sites but when I try the other one the data channel can not come back in the network. Is there a way I can do a range of Data channels for one site and then another set for the second?

Server level Data channel 6000 - 6001

Example site 1- 
Data channel - 6000 is the one I want it to use but it is grayed out and shows 6000-6001
Bindings for 6000 and port 21 are done

Example site 2-
Data channel - 6001 is the one I want it to use but it is grayed out and shows 6000-6001
Bindings for 6001 and port 990 are done

Comment: Do you mean that you have *Data Channel Port Range* box in *FTP Firewall support* pane of IIS manager disabled?

Comment: No it is fine in the server page I just want to set each site to be a different set from the server range.

Comment: So the server defines the data channels you want to use, and the issue you're having is that you can't separate them out for each site on the server? In other words, the server shares the two data channels across both sites? It sounds like you want to limit each site to a specific data channel, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.